# IE11 : disabled input text fields are writable :S

Tags: internet-explorer, input, internet-explorer-11, disabled-input

I found an issue using the latest version of IE11. My disabled input text are grayed out but writable.

Not sure it's something special to my PC (a virtual Win7 64 bit, only used for IE testing, no rare plugin installed).

My IE version is IE 11.0.9600.17280 - 11.0.12

Bug can be reproduced in both 32 and 64 bits version of IE. OS is Windows 7 64 bits.

Testing below code I can update the text box content.

If someone else can reproduce it, or knows about this behavior (bug), please let me know. Help is appreciated.

I found information on similar issue with text input inside disabled fieldtext (fixed), but this is a different issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form>Can you enter this text field and change the content? 
    <input type="text" name="test" disabled="disabled">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried instead of `disabled="disabled"` just `disabled`? or `readonly`?

Comment: I find out about this bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/962368/can-still-edit-input-type-text-within-fieldset-disabled, it is quiet similar

Comment: @dippas: Actually I tried first with just disabled

Comment: @dippas: As I stated in my question, this is a different issue since I do not use fieldset.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn CARET browsing off!!

View -> caret browsing

Rich

Answer (score 1):

As Rich said, the behavior is becasue you have enabled the caret option:

[image]

But if you want to ensure not to enable to write even with the caret option maybe you could add the following style to the input:

```css
input:disabled {
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a issue on my local IE only.

Colleagues with same IE version could not reproduce it.

No idea what the cause is, but will ignore it for now.